# Animation like Radar Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, clock, uianimation

How i can do a UIView animation like a radar?
I already have a UIView with the circles created with drawrect, but how i can create a line, doing a clock animation?

Like the image below : 
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are already having all these images then you only require one radar line animation.

You can rotate radar line using this code:

```
- (void) startAnimation {

CABasicAnimation *radarHand;

radarHand = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];

radarHand.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:fromAngle+M_PI];

radarHand.byValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];

radarHand.duration = 60.0f;

radarHand.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;

}
```

(Guess radar line - semi transparent image is also there with you.)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: How can i use it

Answer (score 0):

You can create `UIView` with size of this circle and with center at the center of the circle, draw line (that starts from the center of this view) and than rotate this view.